# Markers do not show up on my Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I cannot get markers to show up on my google map, here is my code below, what do I need to fix?  Thanks.

```
 <script>
    function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');

        var map_options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.661932, -94.306856),

            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
        var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: LatLng(37.661932, -94.306856),

            title: "About.com Headquarters"
        });
        var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.661932, -94.306856);
        var myMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng2,
            map: map,
            title: "Apple Computer"
        });

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your first marker "myMarker". You are not specifying a map, and you are not instantiating the "LatLng" object, as you should be doing. Changing the first marker like this should fix the issue:

```
 var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.661932, -94.306856),
     map: map,
     title: "About.com Headquarters"
 });
```

The second marker looks fine. The first marker is probably throwing an error, which is causing the second marker not to show up as well.